# Automatically export a working copy from SVN

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Let me start by saying we already backup the repository on the file system, I also create a dump of the repository which is also backed up.

Just tested hotcopy and all it does is create a copy of the repository, which we already backup.

I've been requested to create an automated export of working copies for all projects (ideally using a .bat file run via a scheduler) so, for example, that it can be performed every night out of hours. I cannot seem to be able to find details of how to automate this process using a tool such as svnadmin (their documentation isn't the best).

This is in case everything goes kaput, I can quickly start coding on the text files at a moments notice without having to faff with setting up an svn server, reloading the repository etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) command to checkout a working copy of your project and schedule to [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) to bring the working copy up to date with the repository's state. Alternatively, you can run [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html).

You can use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) to automatically run your script every night.